# want to convert in pdf in asp but shwing error - RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();

Tags: c#

**Code in aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

and it's showing error in 
 **this.Page.RenderControl(hw);**

its showing error like,
**RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();**

i search for solution - **<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation = "false">**

but its not solved.

in my page i have 
**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contnm = "<%= ContentPlaceHolder1.ClientID%>" + "_";
</script>
```

**

may be that's why it's showing error.